# Actors (Label) not being drawn to stage

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx

I have a weird issue that when I try to `draw` a `Stage` with only an `Actor`, a `Label` to be more precise, added to it and nothing seems to be getting drawn.

This is how my setup goes:

I have a `Sprite` (player) being drawn and in another class, which is the HUD, that I draw in a separate `SpriteBatch`, now in the same class I am trying to `draw` the `Stage`, I have ensured that the `Stage` is outside of the HUD's `SpriteBatch.begin()/.end()` calls and that the `Stage` is being drawn after, which should be "above" the HUD.
I have also set the position, of the `Actor`, to be in the middle of the `Stage`

I just can't seem to get this to work.

This is my code for the **Player** class:

```
public void update(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, float delta){   
    // *** REMOVED FOR CLARITY ***
    spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    camera.update();
    hud.render(delta);
}
```

And this is my code for the **HUD** class

```
public void render(float delta){
    spriteBatch.begin();
    spriteBatch.draw(hudBackgroundTexture, position.x, position.y, size.x, size.y);
    // *** REMOVED FOR CLARITY ***
    spriteBatch.end();
    labelLives.setPosition(size.x/2, size.y/2);
    hudStage.act();
    hudStage.draw();
}
```

I'm not receiving any errors, and I know I have initialised my `Stage` and `Label`.

Thanks in advance =]]

Comment: have you added your actor to the stage???

Comment: First of all: make sure you add the Actor to the Stage: `hudStage.addActor(label)`. Then try to call camera.update() before you set the `ProjectionMatrix` to `camera.combined`. Next: you call `hud.render(delta)`, but what you show us is `HUD#render()` without delta. Is there a difference? Or is it only a typing error?

Comment: I am more than positive that I am adding the `Actor` to the `Stage`. I don't know about the order of `camera.update()` and `camera.combined` as I have another class with the same order and works just fine. The delta thing that @Springrbua pointed out was just a typo, which I have changed now =]

Comment: Did you make sure to set your stage's camera to the same camera you're using for your batch?

Comment: @nhydock I put the stage's camera to the same camera for the batch, but then the `HUD` takes up the whole screen, the HUD has a separate `SpriteBatch`, to render above the "world".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haha, well, I found out what was up, it was my font file, you see when I was editing it, I used the text **READY**, so when I saved it, I didn't know that the text written is what is saved, so when I looked at the font.png file, I found that it only contained the letters **ADERY**.

Thanks for the help anyway =]